# Change "contact" photo when making a call

Tags: contacts, google-account

I've started using Google Plus and I want my Android "contact" picture to change to the picture used in G+; a real photo of me. It's currently using an old avatar picture I once set for Google Talk, so when I call them it pops up with a silly avatar instead of my real photo. This shows up as my Phone contact picture as well, not just Google +.

Is there some way to set which image is used either via android, Gtalk or Gmail or something?

I always use Gchat via Gmail, but I don't know where or how I set my Gtalk avatar anymore, and I don't recall setting that picture for myself on my phone ever.

I am on Android 2.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to change this via the "Mail Settings" menu in **Gmail**, under the General Menu is a My Picture menu, where you can select the image used for Google +, Google Voice and apparently the icon used for contacts synched with gmail.